# Random Number Generation - Infection

Tags: matlab

```
InfectionMatrix = zeros(100,100);
InfectionMatrix(50,50) = 1;


    for k = 1:1:90

        [i,j] = find(InfectionMatrix > 0.7);



        %Random Number Generator
        a = 0.0270;
        b = 0.3250;
        RANDOM = (b-a).*rand(8,1) + a;
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



       i(i == 1) = [];
       i(i == length(InfectionMatrix)) = [];
       j(j == 1) = [];
       j(j == length(InfectionMatrix)) = [];



                        InfectionMatrix(i-1,j) = InfectionMatrix(i-1,j)+      RANDOM(1); 
                        InfectionMatrix(i-1,j+1) = InfectionMatrix(i-1,j+1)+  RANDOM(2);
                        InfectionMatrix(i-1,j-1) = InfectionMatrix(i-1,j-1)+  RANDOM(3); 
                        InfectionMatrix(i,j+1) = InfectionMatrix(i,j+1)+      RANDOM(4); 
                        InfectionMatrix(i,j-1) = InfectionMatrix(i,j-1)+      RANDOM(5);
                        InfectionMatrix(i+1,j+1) = InfectionMatrix(i+1,j+1) + RANDOM(6); 
                        InfectionMatrix(i+1,j-1) = InfectionMatrix(i+1,j-1) + RANDOM(7);
                        InfectionMatrix(i+1,j) = InfectionMatrix(i+1,j) +     RANDOM(8); 

       rng('shuffle')

     TooHigh = find(InfectionMatrix > 100);

                  for m = 1:1:length(TooHigh)                      
                InfectionMatrix(TooHigh(m)) = 100;
                 end
    end
h = heatmap(InfectionMatrix)
old_warning_state = warning('off', 'MATLAB:structOnObject');
hs = struct(h);
warning(old_warning_state);

hs.XAxis.TickValues = [];
hs.YAxis.TickValues = [];
```

I want to model kind of a simplistic view of a spreading infection. There  are 2 things I'd like to accomplish.

Id like to know how to change the spread of the infection to be more circular, there are clearly issues with the corner nodes progressing in a star shape.

Id also like to know how to change the bottom half of the map to progress at half the rate of the top, i.e The Random number generation `RANDOM`would be `RANDOM/2`
That kind of idea.

I'd appreciate any help to improve my code that is not relevant to the problems I specified also.

Comment: This question lacks a question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're aiming for but I think you would want to use a 2d convolution of the sort

```
Infected = zeros(100);
Infected(50,50) = 1;
InfectionMatrix = zeros(100);

for k = 1:90
    RANDOM = (b-a).*rand(3,3) + a;
    RANDOM(2,2) = 0;       
    RANDOM = RANDOM .* fspecial('gaussian',3,1);  % sigma=1 3x3 kernel
    InfectionMatrix = InfectionMatrix + conv2(Infected,RANDOM,'same');
    Infected = InfectionMatrix > 0.7;
end
```

You can modulate the random number by a gaussian filter, like fspecial(), to ensure that they fall off at the corners.

Comment: I don't understand this, what would the progression look like over time? How would I implement this in my own code?